# Getting error to read and write from EEEPROM I2C(CAT24C256)

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, i2c, eeprom

When I am running the I2C-Tools of eeprog makefile for read and write data from EEPROM I2C(CAT24C256) through linux.

```
astra@astra-OptiPlex-3020:~/niraj_workspace/eeprog-0.7.6(1)/eeprog-0.7.6$ make clean
rm -f eeprog 24cXX.o
astra@astra-OptiPlex-3020:~/niraj_workspace/eeprog-0.7.6(1)/eeprog-0.7.6$ make all
cc -g -I. -Wall -O2      -c -o 24cXX.o 24cXX.c
cc   eeprog.o 24cXX.o   -o eeprog
```

And After that when I am trying to read or write,I am getting like this.

```
astra@astra-OptiPlex-3020:~/niraj_workspace/eeprog-0.7.6(1)/eeprog-0.7.6$ ./eeprog -f -16 -w 0 -t 5 /dev/i2c-0 0x50
./eeprog: invalid option -- 't'
Error at line 196: Both read and write requested
astra@astra-OptiPlex-3020:~/niraj_workspace/eeprog-0.7.6(1)/eeprog-0.7.6$ ./eeprog -xf /dev/i2cv-0 0x50 -16 -r 0x10:0x20
eeprog 0.7.6, a 24Cxx EEPROM reader/writer
Copyright (c) 2003-2004 by Stefano Barbato - All rights reserved.
  Bus: /dev/i2cv-0, Address: 0x50, Mode: 16bit
Error eeprom_open: No such file or directory
Error at line 244: unable to open eeprom device file (check that the file exists and that it's readable)
```

I am doing right or wrong for this.
And I am running this makefile.

```
CFLAGS=-g -I. -Wall -O2   

all: eeprog 

clean: 
    rm -f eeprog 24cXX.o

eeprog: eeprog.o 24cXX.o

eeprog-static: eeprog.o 24cXX.o
    $(CC) -static -o $@ $?
```

Comment: eeprog has no `-t` option. Why `v` in `/dev/i2cv-0`?

Comment: And with eeprog ,I tried but I am getting core dumped and eeprog not found.astra@astra-OptiPlex-3020:~/niraj_workspace/eeprog-0.7.6(1)/eeprog-0.7.6$ ./eeprog /dev/i2c-0 0x50 -x -r 0x10:0x20
eeprog 0.7.6, a 24Cxx EEPROM reader/writer
Copyright (c) 2003-2004 by Stefano Barbato - All rights reserved.
  Bus: /dev/i2c-0, Address: 0x50, Mode: 8bit
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
astra@astra-OptiPlex-3020:~/niraj_workspace/eeprog-0.7.6(1)/eeprog-0.7.6$ date | eeprog /dev/i2c-0 0x50 -w 0x200
eeprog: command not found

Comment: The "command not found" error is because you used used the command `eeprog` instead of `./eeprog`.

Comment: I am using eeporg instead of ./eeprog then I am getting "command not found".                  astra@astra-OptiPlex-3020:~/gajanan_eclipse/EEPROG$ eeprog /dev/i2c-0 0x50 -x -r 0x22:0x20
eeprog: command not found

Comment: with ./eeprog,getting like this -astra@astra-OptiPlex-3020:~/gajanan_eclipse/EEPROG$ date | ./eeprog /dev/i2c-0 0x50 -w 0x0
eeprog 0.7.6, a 24Cxx EEPROM reader/writer
Copyright (c) 2003-2004 by Stefano Barbato - All rights reserved.
Usage: eeprog [-fqxdh] [-16|-8] [ -r addr[:count] | -w addr ]  /dev/i2c-N  i2c-address

  Address modes: 
 -8  Use 8bit address mode for 24c0x...24C16 [default]
 -16  Use 16bit address mode for 24c32...24C256
  Actions: 
 -r addr[:count] Read [count] (1 if omitted) bytes from [addr]
   and print them to the standard output